# NSLogger in iOS freeze my app

Tags: ios, freeze, nslogger

I am integrate NSLogger into my iOS app, I found that after integrate NSLogger, My app become easy to freeze, especially when there is no internet.
I added code below to main.m, anyone know why?

```
Logger *logger = LoggerGetDefaultLogger();
LoggerSetOptions(logger,
                     kLoggerOption_BufferLogsUntilConnection |
                     kLoggerOption_CaptureSystemConsole |
                     kLoggerOption_BrowseBonjour |
                     kLoggerOption_BrowseOnlyLocalDomain);
LoggerSetupBonjour(logger, NULL, NULL));
```

this is crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: 5278EF6A-1128-49D6-B31A-B6AA03AC856C
CrashReporter Key:   848d8e4999dd36db808023480dc660a86c173fee
Hardware Model:      iPad6,7
Process:             My App [386]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/579502B0-20F3-4C83-82F0-ED50BC79C831/My App.app/My App
Identifier:          com.xiang.My App
Version:             1140 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.xiang.My App [490]


Date/Time:           2016-11-18 13:41:18.1326 +0900
Launch Time:         2016-11-18 13:33:07.3810 +0900
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.1.1 (14B100)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e8d9948 writev + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f909cc0 _CFLogvEx2Predicate + 452
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f909eec _CFLogvEx3 + 408
3   Foundation                      0x00000001903f0454 _NSLogv + 132
4   Foundation                      0x000000019031735c NSLog + 32
5   My App                          0x00000001000511a4 0x100030000 + 135588
6   My App                          0x0000000100050f2c 0x100030000 + 134956
7   My App                          0x000000010008b18c 0x100030000 + 373132
8   My App                          0x0000000100089530 0x100030000 + 365872
9   UIKit                           0x00000001958a7dc0 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 728
10  UIKit                           0x0000000195958b34 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 268
11  UIKit                           0x0000000195a0bd5c _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 292
12  UIKit                           0x00000001959fdb10 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 560
13  UIKit                           0x000000019576c854 _afterCACommitHandler + 168
14  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f8d37dc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
15  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f8d140c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
16  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f8d189c __CFRunLoopRun + 1024
17  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f800048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
18  GraphicsServices                0x0000000191286198 GSEventRunModal + 180
19  UIKit                           0x00000001957e52fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684
20  UIKit                           0x00000001957e0034 UIApplicationMain + 208
21  GroundStation Pro               0x00000001000f27b0 0x100030000 + 796592
22  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018e7e45b8 start + 4
```

Comment: Symbolicate your crash report so you can see exactly where in your app it crashes.

Comment: And show the code that is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should not be adding code to `main.m`. Look into placing code like this in your application delegate.

Secondly, the `0x8badf00d` crash is a known error caused by your application taking too long to start. This may be because you have the log start code in the wrong location as I've said above. Or it may be something else.

As a general rule, anything you have in the startup of your application take may take time, should be either delayed or placed on a back ground thread. Application startup should get the user to the home screen of your app as soon as possible.

Comment: thanks I will move it from main to delegate. but the crash not happen at startup, it happened sometime during user is operating the app